# The probability of finding a peak in an almost sorted ascending table other than the last element (binary search modified Las Vegas random algorithm)

Tags: probability

I have a problem.

We take the table:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16

This table is sorted.

We are looking for the peak element (a peak element is something which is greater than it's neighbors)

Typically, for a sorted ascending table, the peak is always the last element (always sorted first for sorted descending).

Peak is always at least one (there may be many of them).

We can find any peak using binary search - the complexity of $O(log(n))$.
Here is a solution: [**link**](http://www.techiedelight.com/find-peak-element-array/).

The question is as follows.

We have an array sorted in ascending order ($2^n$ elements). There is one exception in this table (second peak). (In the general case is $k$ exceptions)

For example:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 20 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16

Additional peak is $20$ (position $7$ counting from $0$).

We use [**Randomized Binary Search Algorithm**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/randomized-binary-search-algorithm/) to search for the peak.

What is the exact probability that the algorithm will return a peak other than the last element of the array?

Comment: This might sound silly, but why would the algorithm fail?

Comment: Algorithm return good solution - (generally) last element in table - this is peak. But I looking another peak.

Comment: So in the case $k=1$, the random number picked would need to be less than or equal to the index of the local peak, given the number is greater than the index itself. So $20$ is at index $9$. We choose anything between $9$ and $16$ inclusive, it will never find it. The random generator must choose $1$ to $8$ inclusive. That is the probability is all the outcomes in favor divided by all the outcomes. So $\frac 8{16}$

Comment: So for $k = 1$  and the second peak index = $i$, and the table size $2^n$ is $\frac{i}{2^n}$. How is for $k > 1$?

Comment: I think it is complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Let us generalise for the case $k=1$ and some number of elements $2^n$. Let us call the unsorted number $N$. Let us call the index at which $N$ is placed $X$.

The probability this algorithm will return $N$, is dependent on $X$, $N$.

If $N>X+1$, then we have probability of $\frac X{2^n}$ since the algorithm must start at or before the index to find $N$. Because it searches to the right when larger.

If $N=X+1$, then we have probability of $0$ since we always end up at the end, as there is no other peak.

If $N=X$, we have probability of $0$ (this is the trivial case that the element are ascending).

If $N=X-1$, then we have probability of $0$ since we always end up at the end, as there is no other peak.

If $N<X-1$, probability is $\frac {2^n-(X+1)}{2^n}$ since the algorithm would need to start between the number $N$ and the last number $2^n$ inclusive.

For the case $k>1$, it can be complicated, since the algorithm will depend on the placement of the numbers. And the numbers themselves.

Comment: Thanks! However, You doubled the probability for $N > X + 1$. How should it be?

Comment: Sorry, please see the edit for fix. You should consider setting up a bounty for the case $k>1$.

Comment: Are You absolutely sure about the calculations? The binary search for the $2^n$ array will be executed recursively $n$ times. It seems to me that the probability is much lower. Entering the first range where $N$ is located does not guarantee success.

Comment: Ah. I see. The probabilities above assume it only searches once. You can simply use the laws of probability through unions and intersection to find the probability if it searches n times. Essentially take them to the power of n.